# Getting key value using multiple keys in json using java

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured, jsonpath

How do I get key value using multiple keys in java?

Example: I wanted to extract name where id=121 and number=1

```
    [{
        "id": 121,
        "name": "Pants",
        "number": 1,
        "specification": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 121,
        "name": "color",
        "number": 2,
        "specification": ""
    }];
```

Comment: Do you already have Java data class for storing such objects (with 4 fields)?

Comment: You can use jsonPath wildcards to extract such value , use this jsonPath : [?(@.id=='121' && @.number =='1')]

Answer (score 4):

If you have dedicated class like :

```
class A {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int number;
    private String specification;

    //getters and setters method
}
```

Then you can use `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` to create an object from json:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
A[] objects = mapper.readValue(jsonString, A[].class);
```

Now, how it was mentioned by @vader you can use filter methods to get right value:

```
List<A> list = Arrays.stream(objects)
    .filter(obj -> obj.getId().equals("121") && obj.getNumber() == 1)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be done like so

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

    String json = "[{\"id\":121,\"name\":\"Pants\",\"number\":1,\"specification\":\"\"},{\"id\":121,\"name\":\"color\",\"number\":2,\"specification\":\"\"}]";

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);

    final int ID = 121;
    final int NUMBER = 1;

    int size = array.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

      final JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
      final int id = obj.getInt("id");
      final int number = obj.getInt("number");

      if (id == ID && number == NUMBER) {
        System.out.println(obj.getString("name"));
      }
    }

  }
}
```

If you what to something more generic you might want to deserialize this into an object and use Java 8 collection method. This is [a link](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-applying-lambdas-to-java-collections/) I found from a google search.